# I have database contains tables, out which some tables are listed but when I try to access that MySQL says that table does not exists

Tags: mysql, database

I have tried to verify that its entry exists in `information_schema.tables` and I found that there was no entry for that.

Comment: are you using a gui or command line?

Comment: I have tried both gui and commandline.

Comment: what do you get for: select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_name) like '%MY_TABLE%' or describe my_schema.my_table or select * from my_schema.my_table or select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_schema) = 'MY_SCHEMA'?

Comment: Same thing saying table does not exists.